# Disable ng-click for marker and infowindow in angular map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I'm using angular map and I binded ng-click event for it which opens a dialog window. However, I would like to disable ng-click for markers and infowindows. The problem didn't exist when I used plain js for Google Maps and draw markers in controller, but it appeared now when I started drawing markers in html with .

I tried to disable it like that:

```
<div class="map-container" ng-click="clickMarker || getCoords();showDialog($event)">
    <marker ng-disabled="clickMarker"></marker>  
</div>
```

It didn't help. I know that it's possible to event.stopPropagation, but I couldn't catch one that triggers infowindow popup. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expression like this:

```
<div class="map-container" ng-click="clickMarker?null:showDialog($event)">
    <marker ng-disabled="clickMarker"></marker>  
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't help, dialog still appears if I click on marker